# Google spreadsheet conditional format on multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using for activity tracking. There are two different methods that our members can achieve the desired "activity level" and I'm trying to find a way to set conditional formatting to their name field based on a comparison of the values. I'm certain this won't be simple and may even require a script, but I'm not keen on how that will work in Google Docs.

Members can meet the activity goals by either attending a certain number of events, or through "merit points" that are gained through other activities. In my worksheet, I have various fields that are calculated to achieve these numbers, and they display in columns at the end of the month. I have one column for attendance, and another column that tallies their merit points. Each column has it's own conditional formatting, but I'd like to set it up so their member name is highlighted based on the activity.

Currently I'm looking for something that will basically go "if L6=X OR M6=Y then make cell Z color" later I'll want to make it compare the two arguments to a range and make a color based on the overall comparison, but I know I'll need a script with another formula nested to be able to do that with the values. For now, i just want it to make the Name fields a particular color if either to the L or M columns are within a desired range.

Here's a link to a sample of my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhftzbKWmUGaGhqW7zkwjVUVL0bXVvotNVSQl-u5oxQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking some liberties with your ""if L6=X OR M6=Y" I suggest selecting ColumnZ and Format, Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:

```
=or(L1=3,M1>3000)
```

or similar, with a colour of your choice and Range: `Z:Z`.

Comment: Thank you. I modified it to =or(L1>3,M1>3000) and it's working wonderfully to change the text color for the names in columns A and B. Now all I have to do is manually edit L and M to the appropriate columns each month, which takes a matter of seconds. i created a second one using =or(L1<3,M1<3000) to highlight the in-actives as well and overall it's a huge success.